# How to make @NotNull throw runtime exception?

Tags: java

Is there any framework that can throw exception if I pass null as parameter to `@NotNull` annotation? I don't mean static analysis but run-time checks.

If not, how to implement it?

Comment: I dont mean static analise, but runtime behaviour

Comment: Annotations have no runtime effect except that they're visible through reflection.  You'd need to write a bytecode transformer ("enhancer" if you must) to automatically add the null checks.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Not really, It depends on the Retention policy of the annotation

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: Even annotations retained at runtime are not executed like code -- they're just containers of constants that can be read by reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lombok @NonNull](http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html) generates those boilerplate for you. Instead of annotating method with @NotNull, you annotate the parameter @NonNull instead.

```
import lombok.NonNull;

public class NonNullExample extends Something {
   private String name;
   public NonNullExample(@NonNull Person person) {
       super("Hello");
////   if (person == null) {
////       throw new NullPointerException("person");
////   }
       this.name = person.getName();
   }
}
```

See the many questions tagged [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok) to learn more.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Java 6 or a lower version then you can use `Guava` `Preconditions`.

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull(param);
```

However, if you using `Java 7` or a higher version then there is a Utility method in `Objects`.

```
 Objects.requireNonNull(param);
```

And there is an overload that takes string to add a message to the `NullPointerException` that will be thrown

```
Objects.requireNonNull(param,"Param cannot be null");
```

Comment: Java 7+ Objects.requireNotNull(Object o). No external libraries needed.